# How to make specific click trigger link else do something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing this for a "welcome dialog".

This function listens if you click on specific `<div>` and sends you to another web page or closes the welcome `<div>`.

But I think I couldn't make it work for the "close" functionality.

My script in the HTML head:

```
function hideWell() {
    if (("welSolu").on('click hover')) {
        location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
    }
    document.getElementById("welScreen").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("welScreen").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("html").style.overflow = "visible";
}
```

My `<div>`s in the HTML body:

```
<div id="welScreen" onmousedown="hideWell()">
    <div id="welSolu">to go another page click here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `("welSolu").on('click hover')` is not valid... Look at the documentation for on().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use two different functions for that, because it is a good practice that one function does one thing. Event your code has several mistakes, without jquery you can do your thing like this:

```js
function doRedirect(e) {
    // Prevent event propagation to the outer div
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do your redirect
    console.info("redirect");
}

function hideWell(e) {
    // Do the hiding thing
    console.info("hideWell");
}
```

```css
#welScreen {
  padding: 15px;
  background: gray;
}

#welSolu {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="welScreen" onmousedown="hideWell(event)">
    <div id="welSolu" onmousedown="doRedirect(event)">to go another page click here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help. Please, do not forget to mark the answer as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is in the `if` clause - the `on()` method in JQuery uses callback mechanism - its not something you call to "check the status", instead you use it to "register for status change notifications".

So something like this is the intended behavior:

```
$("#welSolu").on('click hover', function() {
    location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
});
```

(although changing the current page when someone hovers over an element in the page is really disruptive, please don't do that).

This code shouldn't be inside the `hideWell()` function - it should be run as part of the ready state handling of your page - i.e. it should be run immediately as the "document becomes ready" but not before that. JQuery has a facility for that, which would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#welSolu").on('click hover', function() {
        location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
    });
});
```

The other part of the function can stay the same as it is and it will get activated as you expect when the user "mouses down" on the part of the div that wasn't handled by the JQuery event handler - though it is likely a good idea to also change that to use JQuery event handling, just to make all the code use the same mechanism: its easier to understand and maintain that way.

So the full replacement code might looks like this:

Script in HEAD:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#welSolu").on('click hover', function() {
        location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
    });
    $("#welScreen").on('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("welScreen").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("welScreen").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("html").style.overflow = "visible";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to attach a function to the onmousedown event. Just set up event listeners for whatever you want. I'm not entirely sure when you want to hide the welcome div, but something like this should work:

```
$('#welSolu').click(function() {
    location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
});

$('#welScreen').click(function() {
    this.hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="welScreen">
    <div id="welSolu">to go another page click here</div>
</div>
```